# Automatic website caching

Tags: browser, download, website, browser-cache, offline-files

For anyone familiar with HTTrack, this program (among others) would seem to potentially be the start of a way to cache websites separate and more durably from the rather limited scope of a browser's native cache. This would be a great way of rebrowsing offline or even limiting the loading time of sites when they are revisited, although ad revenue services would probably be vehemently opposed.

This would be particularly useful, for example, for referring to craigslist postings even after they have been expired / been deleted. Perhaps this could also be integrated into a service like the Wayback Machine (archive.org). Instead of caching all sites, there could be an option to setting a filter to download to sites only from only a certain domain.

Anyone working on such a program?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? A cache, an offline copy and an archive have quite different requirements. There are solutions for each of them. It’s unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: essentially a cache that would enable offline browser functionality -- also for the browser could use to cut down on load times unless it notices a site has been updated.

Comment: You are asking different things with different requirements, and that's why there is different software solutions for each of them. Browsers come with built-in caches that are designed for caching functionality and that do their job very well. HTTrack downloads a snapshot of a website so it can be browsed offline, and it does that job very well.